# How not to create div element when details is close

Tags: angular

How not to create div element when details is close
this code does not work:

```
<details #dtv>
     <summary>Details</summary>
      <div class="xd" *ngIf="dtv.open">lala</div>
</details>
```

Comment: What do you mean in 'close details' how it can be closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container as

```
<ng-container class="xd" *ngIf="dtv.open; else templateA">//
 <div>

  </div>
</ng-container>


<ng-template #templateA>
  
</ng-template>
```

As ng-container does not create an element if condition is not satisfied.

Extract from official documentation:

> ng-container allows us to use structural directives without any
> extra element, making sure that the only DOM changes being applied are
> those dictated by the directives themselves.

Comment: it doesn't work because it doesn't create a div for me when I open it

Comment: I updated the answer, you can try it; lets see if that helps you.